# What is the measure on the Range in Radon-Nikodym Theorem (Possible CtrExample)

Tags: measure-theory

Edit: I guess my question can be boiled down to: if $f$ is a function involved in Radon Nikodym theorem, is the codomain of $f$ always $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure? or always euclidean? or can by anything as long as the measure on range is defined on a Borel Sigma Algebra.

$A\subset B$ be a sub-$\sigma$ algebra. $\mu$ be a probability measure on $B$. Then $\mu$ defines a measure on $A$ via restriction. Def $\nu$ on $A$ via $$\nu(a)=\int_af\,d\mu$$

Then $\nu$ is absolutely continuous measure on $A$ wrt $\mu$. Hence, by Raydon Nikodym, there exists a unique $A-$measuresuble function $E[f|A]=f\,\,\,\mu$ a.e.

I do not think this is true. Consider the space $([0,1],B,\mu)$ where $B$ is the Borel $\sigma$ algebra and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue Measure. Let $A$ be the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $\{[0,1/2]\}$. Then $A$ contains exactly $4$ elements. Define $$v(a)=\int_{a}3x^2d\mu$$
Then $v([0,1/2])=1/8$ and $v([0,1/2]^c)=7/8$. Let $g:=0.25\mathbb I_{x<0.5} + 1.75\mathbb I_{x>0.5}$

Then $v(a)=\int_{a}gd\mu$ However, I'm not sure if $g$ is $A-$Measureable since to define if a function is measurable, we need the algebra on the codomain as well, but that has not been defined. I could define the algebra on the Range$[0,3]$ to be generated by ${[0,3/4]}$ in which case both $f$ and $g$ are measurable.

Source - First half of pg4 here https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/charles.walkden/magic/lecture05.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by "we need the algebra on the codomain as well". To discuss measurability, what you need in the codomain is a topology, and not a measure; the common assumption is that when you consider real or complex valued functions you consider the usual topology.

Your $g$ is a simple function, so it is trivially measurable: the preimage of **any** set by $g$ is either $\varnothing$, $[0,\tfrac12,]$, $(\tfrac12,1]$, or $[0,1]$, so measurable. And for measurability all you need is that preimages of open sets are measurable.

Comment: The Wikipedia for "measurable functions" defined a $\sigma$ algebra on the codomain hence I assumed a measure exists

Comment: That's right, but the common usage [is this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Term_usage_variations). Mostly because to define an integral one needs limits of some kind, so like I said one wants a topology on the codomain (or, equivalently, in the setup you mention, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra).